# VSCode NodeJs: Debugger not stopping at breakpoint (WSL2/Ubuntu18)

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

Using WSL2/Ubuntu18 I've not been able to make the VSCode NodeJs Debugger to stop on the breakpoints of any NodeJs app. When I start the debugger, it runs (I can see the output on the integrated terminal) but breakpoints are simply ignored.

The simple.js file, with a breakpoint on line 3:

[image: Simple JS with Breakpoint at line 3]

The launch.json is set to:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "NodeJs: Launch Program",
            "program": "${file}",
            "request": "launch",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "type": "pwa-node",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I press F5 or click on the "Start Debugging" button on VS Code, the app runs and following appears on the integrated Terminal:

```
/usr/bin/env 'NODE_OPTIONS=--require /home/myuser/.vscode-server/bin/ea3859d4ba2f3e577a159bc91e3074c5d85c0523/extensions/ms-vscode.js-debug/src/bootloader.bundle.js --inspect-publish-uid=http' 'VSCODE_INSPECTOR_OPTIONS={"inspectorIpc":"/tmp/node-cdp.19338-1.sock","deferredMode":false,"waitForDebugger":"","execPath":"/home/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/bin/node","onlyEntrypoint":false,"autoAttachMode":"always","fileCallback":"/tmp/node-debug-callback-ff32d873905abafa"}' /home/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/bin/node ./simple.js 
Debugger attached.
0
1
2
3
4
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

I've already upgraded from Node10 to Node14, but the problem persists.

On another computer using WSL1, and using the same launch.json the debugger stops at the given breakpoints. Do I need to set something additionally on WSL2? For the record, this is what appears on the integrated terminal on the WSL1 computer before it stops at line 3:

```
/usr/bin/env 'NODE_OPTIONS=--require /home/myuser/.vscode-server/bin/ea3859d4ba2f3e577a159bc91e3074c5d85c0523/extensions/ms-vscode.js-debug/src/bootloader.bundle.js --inspect-publish-uid=http' 'VSCODE_INSPECTOR_OPTIONS={"inspectorIpc":"/tmp/node-cdp.787-3.sock","deferredMode":false,"waitForDebugger":"","execPath":"/home/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/bin/node","onlyEntrypoint":false,"autoAttachMode":"always","fileCallback":"/tmp/node-debug-callback-b901b6d6e3e9799b"}' /home/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/bin/node ./simple.js 
Debugger attached.
<Breakpoint hit and stop...>
```

[image: Debugger stops at breakpoint]

Additional info, debugging Python3 files work correctly on both machines.

Both computers have the same VS Code Version installed.

Update:

You can follow the issue on GitHub: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/113283

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the NodeJs App is being run from a symlinked address - so the debugger can not handle it.

Answer from one of the developers of VSCode/NodeJS on github:

> It looks like you have your script symlinked into /bin/nhosko/simple.js, but its actual location is /mnt/c/Users//bin-nhosko/simple.js. In this case you need to specify some flags so that Node will report the linked location that vscode sees and told the debugger about: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_can-i-debug-if-im-using-symlinks. I want to make the debugger smart enough to fix this automatically in microsoft/vscode-js-debug#776.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/113283#issuecomment-750371948

Answer (score 0):

For me in visual studio code in javascript debug terminal I was having this issue

```
--inspect-publish-uid= is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS
```

I moved the visual studio code to the Application folder and it worked out. Earlier it was inside Downloads folder.